# Execution bit not being set

Tags: files, permissions, acl, touch

I have just set up an EC2 instance to play around with and am testing file permissions; however, I notice that the execution bit is not being passed down to the lower level (read and write are, just not execution).

```
[ec2-user@server www]$ touch web/hi
[ec2-user@server www]$ ls -l web/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user apache  0 May 27 19:02 hi
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user apache 43 May 27 05:15 index.php
[ec2-user@server www]$ getfacl --all-effective web/
# file: web/
# owner: ec2-user
# group: apache
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

What am I missing to get the execution bit to pass down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing mkdir instead, that's what most people would be worrying about?

touch doesn't create executable files.  It masks those bits off in the mode parameter to sys_open().  [Source code:](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/touch.c;h=628610a81d1959fc2553e91a15b9e8f26caa4f88;hb=HEAD#l133)

```
 133       /* Try to open FILE, creating it if necessary.  */
 134       fd = fd_reopen (STDIN_FILENO, file,
 135                       O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK | O_NOCTTY, MODE_RW_UGO)
```

Note there is no X in the mode argument.  You can't force programs to create executable (or world-readable, etc) files if they don't allow for it.  A lot of file creation is going to look like that.  Installing executable files is the less common case.

The system calls used by touch are also described by [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Comment: A new dir has the appropriate permissions.